# Using redux state inside HOC in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, higher-order-components

In my react app, I have a `withAuth` HOC which checks if the user is authenticated before the wrapped component is loaded. It looks up the redux store to check auth status and loads the component, if `isAuth` is true. However, I can't access redux store from the HOC. when I try, I get the following error message on the browser. Any help to overcome this problem is highly appreciated.

[image]

**withAuth.js**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { setAuth } from '../actions/Actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function withAuth(WrappedComponent) {
    return (props) => {
        const [isAuth, setAuth] = useState(false);

        useEffect(() => {
            if (props.isAuth) {
                setAuth(true);
            } else {
                props.history.push('/catalog');
            }
        }, [props.history]);

    return isAuth ? <WrappedComponent {...props} /> : <p>Loading..</p>
    };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isAuth: state.isAuth,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setAuth: (status) => dispatch(setAuth(status)),
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withAuth);
```

Comment: You can also use "useSelector()" hook from react-redux to access store in a functional component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a HOC to connect, you have to pass a function component:

```
export default function withAuth(WrappedComponent) {
  const Component = (props) => {
    const [isAuth, setAuth] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (props.isAuth) {
        setAuth(true);
      } else {
        props.history.push('/catalog');
      }
    }, [props.history, props.isAuth]);//forgot dependency here

    return isAuth ? (
      <WrappedComponent {...props} />
    ) : (
      <p>Loading..</p>
    );
  };
  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      isAuth: state.isAuth,
    };
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      setAuth: (status) => dispatch(setAuth(status)),
    };
  };

  return connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(Component);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HOC without connect, we can use this way

```js
// withAuth.js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const withAuth = OriginalComponent => {

  const NewComponent = (props) => {

    const { isUser } = useSelector( state => state.root.user )

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const setUser = (key, payload) => dispatch({type:'SET_USER', key: key, payload: payload })

    return <OriginalComponent {...props} isAdmin={isAdmin} isUser={isUser} setUser={setUser} />;

  }

  return NewComponent;
}

export default withAuth
```

```js
// MyAnyPage.js
import withAuth from 'withAuth'

const MyAnyPage = (props) => {
  return (<>
      <button onClick={e=> props.setUser('name', 'new_name')} >set user name</button>

      <button onClick={e=> props.setUser('email', 'new_email')} >set user name</button>
   </>)
}

export default withReduxUser(MyAnyPage)
```